# comparing ddb timestamp of different precision

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, timestamp

My Java code truncates Instant string representations after the seconds field if the decimal part is zero. For example, it stores `1980-01-01T00:00:00.123456Z` but will store `1980-01-01T00:00:00Z` instead of `1980-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z`. If stored in Amazon DynamoDB, will timestamp comparison work properly?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not have a timestamp data type, for Instant like you show there they are stored as ISO 8601 strings. For that reason it provides you string comparisons lexicographically.

> Lexicographical comparison is a technique used for sorting words alphabetically by comparing the characters in a string sequentially from left to right. The order of precedence used when comparing the characters in a string is:

> 1. Digits
> 2. Uppercase letters
> 3. Lowercase letters

[Src](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/data/9781847197344/5/ch05lvl1sec01/what-is-lexicographical-comparison#:%7E:text=Lexicographical%20comparison%20is%20a%20technique,Digits)

So the short answer to your question is: Yes. So long as all of your timestamps are the same.